# Rewrite simple ruby function to use a block

Tags: ruby, function, yield

I do not know the correct terminology. I tried to google it and could not find anything for that reason.

I am writing a Ruby library, and I want to rewrite the functions so they work as below as I prefer it for readability (inside a block?)

I have a function that does this

```
@dwg = Dwg.new("test.dwg")
@dwg.line([0,0,0],[1,1,0])
@dwg.save
```

I want to rewrite it so it works like this

```
Dwg.new("test.dwg") do

   line([0,0,0],[1,1,0])
   save

end
```

Can you outline the way I go about this?

Comment: A method called `save` may be useful if you're not using a block, but isn't it redundant if you are using a block?

Comment: good point, especially since i am passing the file name to the function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define `Dwg`'s initializer to take a block, and then yield to that block with `instance_eval`, like so:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(name, &block)
    @name = name
    instance_eval &block
  end

  def show_name
    puts 'My name is ' + @name
  end
end

MyClass.new('mud') do
  show_name
end

# >> My name is mud
```

For more information, see the "Blocks for Interface Simplification" section in the recently Creative-Commons-licensed [Chapter 2](http://sandal.github.com/rbp-book/pdfs/ch02.pdf) of Gregory Brown's excellent [Ruby Best Practices](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com) book.  (Its author and publisher are gradually CCing the entire thing, but you can of course still buy a copy to support the work.  The iPhone edition is particularly affordable.)

Comment: Be sure to change the line `instance_eval &block` to `instance_eval &block if block_given?` if you would still like to support the case where `new` is called without a block otherwise you will get `ArgumentError: block not supplied` when you do.